# hover effect on sidebar multilevel menu in AdminLTE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've added hover effect on sidebar multilevel drop-down menu in AdminLTE[default action is click to expand it]

Which is working, but the problem is if go to level 3, and jump outside form is collapses the whole menu which is not what i want, if i jump outside of level 3 it should only collapse level 3 not level 1 and 2.

Here's the js code for it:

```
$('.treeview').hover(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    if(!(_this.hasClass('active'))){
      _this.addClass('active');
      _this.children().find('treeview-menu').addClass('menu-open');
    } else{
      _this.removeClass('active');
      _this.children().find('treeview-menu').removeClass('menu-open');
    }
  })
```

And this the structure of HTML:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two</a></li>
                <li class="treeview">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li class="treeview">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li class="treeview">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://adminlte.io/docs"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Documentation</span></a></li>
        <li class="header">LABELS</li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-red"></i> <span>Important</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow"></i> <span>Warning</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-aqua"></i> <span>Information</span></a></li>
      </ul>
```

Here's the [working demo](http://vehiclerescue.in/admin/index.html) for the same. Just hover on multilevel drop-down menu, and go to level 3 and try to move your mouse away from it, it'll collapses the whole menu, and i'm unable to check other sub-level menu beneath it.

Hop you understand the problem.

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: are not it supposed to do that ? , you writing code on hover event , when it lost focus  it will collapse

Comment: any solution for that?? I want hover effect only.

Comment: dont say you want hover effect only (its taking our thoughts in complete direction now) , you should say you want it on button hover

Comment: As a solution you can use mix of bootstrap collapsible functionality and vertical navbar